# cache auth0 public key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm using auth0 for authentication and using one of their provided methods (copied below) to confirm the jwt token. The solution they provide hits their service on every request to my server, which is making the requests take up to 1 second to complete.

I'm trying to cache the public key that is generated by the method they provide but having no luck. At first I thought I can store it in `Rails.cache` but then realized the method creates an `OpenSSL` object, not a string, and when I try `Rails.cache.write('KEY', openSslObject)` and access it with `Rails.cache.fetch('KEY')` I'm getting nil returned

I also tried to use a block with the rails cache fetch:

```
cached_jwks_hash = Rails.cache.fetch("JWKS_HASH", expires_in: 10.hours) do
  get_jwks_hash
end
```

but still get nil

The `get_jwks_hash` method below returns the following: `{"key"=>#<OpenSSL::PKey::RSA:0x007fe29c545ef8>}`

what would be the best way to cache this data? is it possible to store this in a variable in memory?

```
  def verify(token, jwks_hash)
    JWT.decode(token, nil,
               true, # Verify the signature of this token
               algorithm: 'RS256',
               iss: "https://#{ENV["AUTH0_DOMAIN"]}/",
               verify_iss: true,
               aud: ENV["AUTH0_API_AUDIENCE"],
               verify_aud: true) do |header|
      jwks_hash[header['kid']]
    end
  end

  def get_jwks_hash
    jwks_raw = Net::HTTP.get URI("https://#{ENV["AUTH0_DOMAIN"]}/.well-known/jwks.json")
    jwks_keys = Array(JSON.parse(jwks_raw)['keys'])
    Hash[
      jwks_keys
      .map do |k|
        [
          k['kid'],
          OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(
            Base64.decode64(k['x5c'].first)
          ).public_key
        ]
      end
    ]
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after doing research, I see the problem. The key is not being saved because the `rails.cache.fetch` method is utilizing a `null_store` which doesnt actually store any data. In my `config/environments/development` file theres the following code:

```
  if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=172800'
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end
```

and since I dont have a `tmp/caching-dev.txt` file, the `null_store` is being used. The second to last line can be updated to read

`config.cache_store = :memory_store` or whatever kind of store you like